# Textbook Recommendation

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm looking for a textbook that would expand upon the results that are covered in a typical upper division linear algebra class, but would still be useful to problems covered in a first upper div linear course.

Any recommendations?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is "upper division"?

Comment: Having no idea of what you mean by upper division, my recommendation for a "second course in linear algebra" textbook would be "Linear Algebra Done Right."

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified that. For a full description of the difference see this link http://www.unr.edu/Documents/provost/provosts-office/forms/CCLwrUprDiv.pdf.

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Linear-Algebra-Its-Applications-Peter/dp/0471751561/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1424823532&sr=8-2&keywords=peter+lax